# HP Laptop simply won't turn on - The small red light is glowing DESPITE being plugged off the battery cable

Tags: laptop, hp-laptop

I tried to do a hardware setup with taking the battery out but i don't have the proper screwdrivers to do that.

Is there another solution to it?

This red small light at the right side glows all the time, so does this one small white light on the left side

HP Laptop Model 15-dw0019nw, that's my modell

Comment: In your HP documentation, what screwdriver was specified? What specific model do you have?

Comment: HP Laptop Model 15-dw0019nw, i actually have somewhere a screwdriver which might fit (it's because of the very very small screws) but i'd have to wake up my grandpa to search for it right now and it's 11pm here

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8FJvObDaM8     4 PI Philips screws

Comment: Yes but is this the only way right now to solve my problem, to take out the battery so i can perform a complete reset? can i do it right now without taking out the battery and stuff? i tried pressing the power button for a minute, it does not work

Comment: Sorry for asking but I REALLY need this laptop right now and I don't know what i can do

Comment: Nor do we, with the information you've provided. Have you tried to force shutdown by holding the power button? Have you tried going to BIOS? What happened *before* this issue???

Comment: Laptop won't go on -> I charged it -> Still won't go on -> Houston, we have a Problem. That's what has happened. Nothing more, nothing less. I tried to hold the power button for a minute, didn't do nothing. If I plugged my laptop off the battery cable the red light and white light on the sides were lighting despite no cable plugged in. This is ALL what happened, literally. I can't go to BIOS because my laptop simply won't turn on, absolutely NO sound whatsoever